# Trigger another datetimepicker using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I want to open `datepicker` once I select date in another picker. For this we can see so many suggestions and answers in `datepicker` but I could not find solution for `datetimepicker`. The default `datetimepicker` I have used in my project is this

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove',
        inline: true
    }
});
```

try

```
$( "#QuoteDate" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0, 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#DueDate" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#DueDate" ).datepicker('show');
        }, 16);
    }
});
$( "#DueDate" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
});
```

If I try to code like `onSelect`: as in `datepicker` it's not accepting. Please anyone helps me to find solution for this. `onSelect` date in this picker will call another picker.

Comment: Which datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: Can you post a working example here or in JSFiddle so that the issue can be reproducible?

Comment: did you try adding different classes in your `.datetimepicker()` function like `$('.mypickerOne').datetimepicker()` and `$('.mypickerTwo').datetimepicker()`

Comment: No.,I tried with example of datepicker.

Comment: Confusing. You are showing code for `datepicker` and for `datetimepicker` and not clear what is what. Provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: I have the code for datepicker but I need to change it for datetimepicker

Comment: Create a demo that shows exactly what you are wanting

Comment: okie i will create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have linked datetimepicker take a look at [Linked Pickers](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers) example in the docs.

You have to add a listner to [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event since the datetimepicker has no `onSelect` option. Note that [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange):

> Fired when the date is changed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> e = {
>     date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>     oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> }
> ```

You can use [`show()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#show) function to make the second datetimepicker open.

Here a full live example:

```js
var icons = {
  time: "fa fa-clock-o",
  date: "fa fa-calendar",
  up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
  down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
  previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
  next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
  today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
  clear: 'fa fa-trash',
  close: 'fa fa-remove',
  //inline: true
};

$('#QuoteDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  useCurrent: false,
  minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
  maxDate: moment().add(2, 'years'),
  icons: icons
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
  console.log('change', e.date, e.oldDate);
  if( 
    ( e.date && !e.oldDate ) ||
    ( e.date && e.oldDate && !e.date.isSame(e.oldDate, 'day') )
  ){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#DueDate').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    }, 16);
  }
  $('#DueDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});

$('#DueDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  useCurrent: false,
  minDate: moment().startOf('day'),
  maxDate: moment().add(2, 'years'),
  icons: icons
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
  $('#QuoteDate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='QuoteDate'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='DueDate'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you are using datetimepicker, you can have  `minDate: moment().startOf('day')` instead of `minDate: 0` and `maxDate: moment().add(2, 'years')` instead of `maxDate: "+2Y"` (see moment [`startOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) docs for more info).

As suggested in the [Linked Pickers](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers) example you have to use [`useCurrent: false`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) option.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `change` event, so when you have picked a date in one of the datepicker, you can get a callback fired that it is changed, after that in openAnotherDatePicker function, you can try to get the selected value from the event of using jquery `.val()` function and pass the selected date to the next datepicker

UPDATE: here is live and working example for xdan datetimepicker:

```js
var setMinDate = function( currentDateTime ){
 this.setOptions({minDate:currentDateTime});
};

$('#QuoteDate').datetimepicker({
  format:'d-m-Y h:i',
  onChangeDateTime:openAnotherDatePicker,
  closeOnDateSelect:true
 });
$('#DueDate').datetimepicker({
  format:'d-m-Y h:i',
  onShow:setMinDate,
  closeOnDateSelect:true
 })

function openAnotherDatePicker( selectedDate ) {
 $( "#DueDate" ).val($( "#QuoteDate" ).val());
 $( "#DueDate" ).datetimepicker('show');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<p>
Start <br /><input id="QuoteDate" type="text" value="12-11-2017 06:24">
<br />
End <br /><input id="DueDate" type="text" value="13-11-2017 06:24">
</p>
```

Comment: @KavyaShree, see updated answer, that is exactly what you want to achieve, at least  what i have  understood, from your code and from the website in your previous comment

Comment: @KavyaShree i have updated answer for datetimepicker